# Is there a real function $f$ on $(0..1)$ such that $x·f·\log f = 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, implicit-function

I’m looking for a real-valued function $f$ on $(0..1)$ such that $x · f · \log f = 1$. Is there such function? Is it integrable on $(0..1)$?

Why? This could yield an integrable function $f$ such that $f · \log f = 1/x$ is not integrable on $(0..1)$. That’s what I’m really interested in. But that’s a separate question maybe.

Comment: Do you maybe want it to be defined on the open interval $(0, 1)$? Otherwise you could set $x=0$ in your condition to find that $0 = 0\cdot f(0)\cdot \log f(0) = 1.$

Comment: @Sobi Ah, yes. Alternatively, I meant the condition to hold almost everywhere. I’m only interested in integrability properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function, in terms of the Lambert W function, is
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{xW(1/x)}
$$
The graph looks like this
[image: with W]

Although $f$ goes to $+\infty$ as $x \to 0$ more slowly than $1/x$, it still goes to $+\infty$ fast enough that the integral $\int_0^1 f(x)\;dx$ diverges.
We can see this from the antiderivative.  Function
$$
F(x) = \frac{1}{W(1/x)}-\log\big(W(1/x)\big) .
$$
satisfies $F'(x) = f(x)$.
Now as $x \to 0^+$, we have $W(1/x) \to +\infty$, so $1/W(1/x) \to 0$ and $-\log(W(1/x)) \to -\infty$.  So $F(x) \to -\infty$, which means $\int_x^1 f(t) \;dy = F(1) - F(x) \to +\infty$.

Comment: Great, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Pick $x\in (0,1)$, what you want to find is $y$ such that $$y^y=e^{\frac 1x}$$

Note that $e^{\frac 1x}\in (e,\infty)$ and that  $z\mapsto z^z$ maps $[1,\infty)$ bijectively onto itself.

Since $(e,\infty)\subset [1,\infty)$, the equation (in $y$) $$y^y=e^{\frac 1x}$$ has a unique solution in $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn’t clear. See my edit …

Comment: @k.stm I edited as well.

Comment: Neat, thank you! Oh, can one say anything about the integrability of $f$?

Comment: You're welcome. The answer is still incomplete though, since you added a question about integrability.